# Swift string doesn't conform to anyobject

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Just a bit silly question and answered many times, but nevertheless i can't understand

```
    while let element = enumdirs?.nextObject() as? String {
        println(element)
    }
```

The above causes error: Swift string doesn't conform to anyobject, so with as ,but

```
    while let element = enumdirs?.nextObject() {
        println(element as? String)
    }
```

works perfectly. What the problem with casting in while statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`AnyObject` can represent an instance of any *class* type. A conditional cast from
`AnyObject` to `String` works only because `String` is bridged to `NSString` if necessary.

However, this seems not to work with the optional chaining in

```
while let element = enumdirs?.nextObject() as? String { ... }
```

so this might be a compiler bug. It works as expected if you cast to `NSString` instead:

```
while let element : String = enumdirs?.nextObject() as? NSString { ... }
```

or unwrap explicitly:

```
while let element = enumdirs!.nextObject() as? String { ... }
```

But the better solution might be

```
if let enumdirs = NSFileManager.defaultManager().enumeratorAtPath(...) {
    while let element = enumdirs.nextObject() as? String {
        println(element)
    }
}
```

i.e. unwrap the enumerator with an optional binding *before* using it in
the loop.